# Add filter and sorting functionality in dynamic columns in a datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have created a complete dynamic PrimeFaces datatable (since column number, header is variable). 
Header datatype:

```
Map<String, String> orgUnitDataTableColumnHeader;
```

Table row content:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> orgUnitDataTableRows
```

And I am population data like
        orgUnitDataTableRows = new ArrayList>();

```
for (List<OrgUnitTO> rowData : wholeData) {
    if (rowData == null || rowData.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    int j = 0;
    for (OrgUnitTO columnData : rowData) {
        m.put("Column" + j, columnData.getUnitName());
        j++;
    }
    orgUnitDataTableRows.add(m);
}
```

My output.xhtml is like

```
<p:dataTable id="dataMain" value="#{orgUnitBean.orgUnitDataTableRows}"
    var="row">
    <p:columns
        headerText="#{orgUnitBean.orgUnitDataTableColumnHeader[column]}"
        value="#{orgUnitBean.orgUnitDataTableColumns}" var="column">
#{row[column]}
```

Now I am getting table as i expected. 
What I want to know is how to attach sorting and filter functioning to this datatable.

Comment: I honestly, seriously hope you've seen [the PrimeFaces columns showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml)

Comment: @Kukeltje, I have seen that. What is issue here is row is not referring to List<object> here. ie in primeface demo, each record is linked to one object. Here it is not

Comment: Next time please state so initially in your question. See [ask].

Comment: Then try if you can make some List<MyVirtualRecord>. And you can even refer to other object and use e.g. the colIndex

Comment: @Kukeltje, I am not able to understand ur answer. I cannot make it likeber o MyVirtualRecord object. Table has everything dynamic:  Number of column , header etc. Metadata of table is coming from database

Comment: But your `orgUnitBean.orgUnitDataTableRows` contains everything to display according to your code, so also everything to filter on

Comment: @Kukeltje,yes it has every data. But problem is different component of same row is not belonging to same object type (i guess). so when I am sorting, in display, records are not coming. I am trying to sort using  "sortBy="#{orgUnitBean.orgUnitDataTableColumns}""